# I need the perfect join

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

I have three tables that look like this

**Table A**

```
TIME_EFFECTIVE            DESCRIPTION    ID    DATAVAL
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          1     1
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          2     2
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescB          1     3
1998/01/11 11:00:00 AM    DescA          2     4
```

**Table B**

```
HOUR                      DESCRIPTION    ID    OSO
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          1     10
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          2     34
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescB          1     12
1998/01/11 11:00:00 AM    DescA          2     40
```

**Table C**

```
DESCRIPTION    CVAL    VVAL
DescA          12      1
DescB          34      2
```

And I want this... for all TIME_EFFECTIVE after a certain date...

**The Resulting Table**

```
TIME_EFFECTIVE            DESCRIPTION    ID    DATAVAL   OSO   CVAL    VVAL
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          1     1         10    12      1
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescA          2     2         34    12      1
1998/01/11 12:00:00 AM    DescB          1     3         12    34      2
1998/01/11 11:00:00 AM    DescA          2     4         40    12      1
```

One record per TIME_EFFECTIVE, DESCRIPTION and ID. No duplicates of these three fields combined.

What is my perfect ORACLE SQL join function???

**PS**
My resulting table should have no more rows than Table A.

Comment: Hint:  `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use some JOIN

```
  select a.TIME_EFFECTIVE, a.DESCRIPTION, a.ID, a.DATAVAL, b.OSO, c.CVAL, c.VVAL
  from table_a a 
  inner join table_b b on a.TIME_EFFECTIVE = b.HOUR 
        and a.DESCRIPTION = b.DESCRIPTION 
            and a.ID = b.ID
  inner join  table_c on c.DESCRIPTION = a.DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `INNER JOIN` ?

Also, looking at your resulting table, it does not seem to match. Shouldn't `VVAL` for `DescB` be `1`? If not, then there is some step missing...

Answer (score 3):

There is a small problem with VVAL in table C, line `('DescB', 34, 1)`  Your output requests a 2, but in the table it is 1.  If this is 2 you will get the desired output.

```
SELECT A.*
      ,B.OSO
      ,C.CVAL
      ,C.VVAL
  FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.TIME_EFFECTIVE = B.HOUR AND A.DESCRIPTION = B.DESCRIPTION AND A.ID = B.ID
            INNER JOIN C ON A.DESCRIPTION = C.DESCRIPTION
```

Gives output:

```
TIME_EFFECTIVE          DESCRIPTION ID          DATAVAL     OSO         CVAL        VVAL
----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1998-01-11 00:00:00.000 DescA       1           1           10          12          1
1998-01-11 00:00:00.000 DescA       2           2           34          12          1
1998-01-11 00:00:00.000 DescB       1           3           12          34          2
1998-01-11 11:00:00.000 DescA       2           4           40          12          1
```